# mac which finds the wrong directory for gcc

Tags: macos, gcc

Way beyond my depth here. I have installed gcc using brew. It's located in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc` and the directory there is called 9.1.0. But when I type `which gcc` in a terminal it returns `/usr/bin/gcc`. In /usr/bin there is a file called gcc created by root with group wheel (If I remember what the columns mean). It's not a symlink. It's some kind of binary file.

When I type `gcc --version`, I get back

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: This is a system — i.e. not from brew (AFAIU) — clang, that pretends to be gcc. It is not really a "wrong" gcc executable, just happens to be not the one you want :) (How is the system to know which one it is?) Check your `PATH` environment variable. You can set it to what you want before compiling with e.g. `export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar:$PATH`. P.s.: I suggest adding the `macos` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler in `/usr/bin/gcc` is supplied by Apple.

**homebrew** installs packages to `/usr/local/Cellar` and creates symbolic links to whatever it installs in `/usr/local/bin`. So, if you want to use the **homebrew** GCC, you need to see what it is called with:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/gcc*
```

It is probably `gcc-9`. Now you need to make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is on your PATH before (i.e. ahead of) `/usr/bin`. So, you can do:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Now you can do:

```
gcc-9 --version
```

In general, you want to put that `export` statement in your login script, probably `$HOME/.profile`, so things are always set correctly when you log in.